# iOS/objective C: Display JSON feed in table

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, tableview

I am trying to display a JSON feed in a tableview.  While there are many tutorials and questions on SO about json, none seem to address this question (without suggesting complex frameworks).

So far, I have been able to get the JSON feed into an array.  I know how to display a table once you have an object as the datasource. However, I am missing the code to convert the feed into an object suitable for display in the table.

Code so far:

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
//get JSON feed           
        dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^{
            NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: kLatestKivaLoansURL];
           [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fetchedData:) withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES];
        });
    }
//convert to array    
    - (void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responseData {      
        NSError* error;
        NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData 
      NSLog(@"about to print json: %@",json);
        NSArray* latestLoans = [json objectForKey:@"loans"];
         }
    //Code to convert FEED INTO OBJECT IS NOT WORKING: I have...
- (NSArray*) convertFeedtoObject:(NSArray*)feed {
    loanObject *loan = nil;
    NSMutableArray * loans = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSInteger loansCount = 10;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < loansCount; i++) {
         [loans addObject: loan]
}
}

    //In the tableview delegate method:

    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        //This sets datasource:
//getloans method does not exist
        Loans *loan = [self.getLoans objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    //This sets place in storyboard VC
      IDTVCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
        cell.loan = loan;
          if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[IDTVCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                      reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
        }

        NSString * loanTitle = loan.loan;
       cell.Name = loanTitle;
        return cell;
    }
```

Would appreciate any suggestions on how to get this working.

Comment: where you call this method convertFeedtoObject and you get count on loans

Answer (score 0):

Well after fetching data you need to call
`[self.tableView reloadData]` and please write down the other delegate and datasource methods of tableview `tableViewNumberOfRows` is needed for this to work, and do set the tableview datasource and delegate to self.

## EDIT

This should be your code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^{
        NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: kLatestKivaLoansURL];
       [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fetchedData:) withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES];
    });
}

- (void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responseData {      
    NSError* error;
    NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData 
  NSLog(@"about to print json: %@",json);
    NSArray* latestLoans = [json objectForKey:@"loans"];
   [self.getLoans removeAllObjects];
    self.getLoans = [self convertFeedtoObject:latestLoans]; //add this line
     }

- (NSArray*) convertFeedtoObject:(NSArray*)feed {
loanObject *loan = nil;
NSMutableArray * loans = [NSMutableArray array];
NSInteger loansCount = 10;
int i;
for (i = 0; i < loansCount; i++) {
     [loans addObject: loan]
}
[self.tableview reloadData]; //add this line
}

//add this method
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section      {

 return [self.getLoans count];
}
```

Comment: As commented in my code, I have not yet written a getLoans method-it is just a placeholder.  What would getLoans look like?